# Can I access database without installing SQL server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, localdb

I am working on an ERP Project, using sql server for database.

Now when I deploy the project, I have to install sql server which uses a lot of storage and time is also wasted. As the client is never going to fire any query. Thus, having no need of the development environment. So, is there any option to overcome this.

Local DB is one of the option but having difficulties in configuring it. If anybody ever used it and Please help me out. Or if there's any other option please help me with that

**NOTE: I am using asp.net as front end technology**

Comment: If you're having problems configuring `localdb` it's that you should be asking about. At the end of the day, if you want to use SQL Server as a back end, you need to have some form of SQL Server installed; be that local or remotely.

Comment: Is it necessary to have management studio to configure localDB

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to do, but if you want your app to connect to an SQL Server database, you will need at least the OLE DB Driver to be installed on your server.

It will allow your app to connect to an SQL Server instance, which can be running on any other machine.

In complement you could have a look at this : https://www.connectionstrings.com/ 
and this https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I need this to reduce the size of the application. If I deploy the software with sql server setup, eventually the size of the project increases